# How does PHP ActiveRecord correlate the singular class name to the table name?

Tags: phpactiverecord

I'm still a bit confused by how the following works:

```
your table name would be "people" 
class Person extends ActiveRecord\Model {}
```

So thats what i did with my table: `posts`.

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord\Model{}
```

At no point did I have to specify `Post` is actually equal to the table `posts`. So where/how does this magic happen? How would I override it if need be?

What about in instances like:

```
class fish = table fish
class goose = table geese
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the static `$table_name` in your model, see [php-AR conventions](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Conventions).

Comment: Thanks. Would you know where I can read more about what the rules are when it comes to the mapping of table names to class names?

Comment: Well, it's only briefly documented in the above link - the table name is the plural of the class name. phpAR takes into account some irregular and uncountable nouns too, if you want to find out all the details, take a look at the code - see `\ActiveRecord\Utils::pluralize()`